# Screen turns off when I move my MacBook when it is on the sleeve

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen-lock

I've noticed that when my laptop is on its [sleeve](http://www.outfityours.com/incase-icon-sleeve-for-15-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-black-slate/) and I slide my laptop on it the screen goes black. This doesn't happen when I have the laptop on my lap. Its consistently reproducible. It's somewhat annoying as sometimes when I adjust the laptop on the sleeve the screen goes black. Does anybody know why this happens?

Is some static being created when the laptop is moved when on the sleeve that causes the laptop screen to go black and back to the lock screen?

Comment: This is happening to me when moving a MBPr across a closed MBA :) the latches must be interfering with each other.

Comment: @vektor It would happen as long as you bring any magnetic part next to the MBP!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because the [sleeve](http://www.outfityours.com/incase-icon-sleeve-for-15-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-black-slate/) has a "**Magnetic snap closure with no zippers**" which actually mimics the magnetic latch that's triggered while the lid of the MacBook is closed which turns off the screen.

I've noticed this happen to me a few times in different situations when I would put my iPhone on the hand rest part of the MacBook or If i left my Adonit Jot Pro(which has a magnet to attach itself to the iPad) stylus very close to my MacBook.

[image]

You can try to reproduce the effect by taking a magnet over the marked location (*at least on my non-retina MacBook Pro it happens over there, not sure if the position has been changed on Retina MBP)*

**EDIT** - I now have a MacBook Retina, I haven't noticed this effect anymore. I'm guessing the position of the magnetic latch has been moved.

Comment: very nice, I didn't know that!